# Why is Polars running my "then" function even if the "when" condition is false?

Tags: python, python-polars

Given this DataFrame:

```py
d1 = pl.DataFrame({
    'x': ['a', None, 'b'],
    'y': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]
})
print(d1)

shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬─────┐
│ x    ┆ y   │
│ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ f64 │
╞══════╪═════╡
│ a    ┆ 1.1 │
│ null ┆ 2.2 │
│ b    ┆ 3.3 │
└──────┴─────┘
```

I want to transform rows with non-null `x` into some `f(x,y)=999`, else `null`.

```py
# Using [print(d), 999][-1] hack just to trace calls
d2 = d1.select(
    pl.when(pl.col('x').is_not_null())
    .then(pl.struct(['x','y']).apply(lambda d: [print(d), 999][-1])) 
    .otherwise(None)
    .alias('s'))

print(d2)
```

Why this `print(d)` output despite correct `d2`? I expected the `then` to be evaluated only if `x.is_not_null`.

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 1.1}
{'x': None, 'y': 2.2}  <<<< why?
{'x': 3, 'y': 3.3}

shape: (3, 1)
┌──────┐
│ s    │
│ ---  │
│ i64  │
╞══════╡
│ 999  │
│ null │
│ 999  │
└──────┘
```

Why is the `print` executed even for the `(null,2.2)` row?

Comment: The `.then` function is going to get executed regardless of whether its results are used or not, so its parameter must be evaluated.  It's just a cute way to spell normal function calls.  There's no short-circuiting.

Comment: Ouch! Good to know. That means `then` might have to duplicate all the predicates in the `when` clause, if they might lead to undefined behaviors. Is that a consequence of everything being vectorized, so the `then` series and `otherwise` series are just combined with `when` as a bit-mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for why this happens, it's because `.when()` and `.then()` branches are executed in parallel, the "masking" is done afterwards.

You can `.apply()` the result of `.when().then()`

<sub>`.otherwise(None)` is the default</sub>

```
df.with_columns(apply = 
   pl.when(pl.col('x').is_not_null())
     .then(pl.col("x"))
     .apply(lambda self: [print(f"{self=}"), self][1])
)
```

```
self='a'
self='b'
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬───────┐
│ x    ┆ y   ┆ apply │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ f64 ┆ str   │
╞══════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ a    ┆ 1.1 ┆ a     │
│ null ┆ 2.2 ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 3.3 ┆ b     │
└──────┴─────┴───────┘
```

This only prints twice because `.apply()` skips nulls by default.

It doesn't appear to be working with a struct though:

```
df.with_columns(apply = 
   pl.when(pl.col('x').is_not_null())
     .then(pl.struct("x", "y"))
     .apply(lambda self: [print(f"{self=}"), self][1])
)
```

```
self={'x': 'a', 'y': 1.1}
self={'x': None, 'y': None}
self={'x': 'b', 'y': 3.3}
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────────────┐
│ x    ┆ y   ┆ apply       │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---         │
│ str  ┆ f64 ┆ struct[2]   │
╞══════╪═════╪═════════════╡
│ a    ┆ 1.1 ┆ {"a",1.1}   │
│ null ┆ 2.2 ┆ {null,null} │
│ b    ┆ 3.3 ┆ {"b",3.3}   │
└──────┴─────┴─────────────┘
```

Polars does consider a struct of all null values as null:

```
df.with_columns(apply = 
   pl.when(pl.col('x').is_not_null())
     .then(pl.struct("x", "y"))
     .is_null()
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬───────┐
│ x    ┆ y   ┆ apply │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ f64 ┆ bool  │
╞══════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ a    ┆ 1.1 ┆ false │
│ null ┆ 2.2 ┆ true  │
│ b    ┆ 3.3 ┆ false │
└──────┴─────┴───────┘
```

So I think this could possibly be a "bug".

Comment: Ah, thank you!! I posted comment above to @Tim before I saw yours. At least I am getting closer to the right track :-) ... And you straight-up read my mind on `struct`, I think I've managed to send Polars `apply` into a tailspin on that a couple of times. Not confident enough yet to file a report on it